# Animating an overlay color over a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, text

I'm trying to come up with a creative solution to give this particular effect:

[image]

My initial idea: A dynamically sized rectangle with a chroma key shader effect will slide into place over the text.  However, I do not want to kill the fidelity of the text edges which tends to happen with shaders.

I also considered using the FormattedText class, though I'm not sure it supports what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions?

*EDIT*
To clarify, the text will be essentially a 'TabItem'.  I would like the highlighted block to float across all tab items to the selected item.  They are currently laid out in a Canvas with logic handling their positioning.  A simple animation would not suffice it would seem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the effect you want.  This uses a gradient brush for the color, but it uses 3 gradient stops to make sure that the color changes immediately from one to the next with no gradient in between.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="TestingWPF.TestWindow"
    d:DesignWidth="477" d:DesignHeight="214"
    Background="Black">

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="74" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="WhiteOffset" Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="GrayOffset" Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WhiteOffset" From="0" To="1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GrayOffset" From="0" To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
        Some Text
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

Comment: Appreciate your response.  I considered this but decided it wasn't a truly viable option because I intend to use the highlight as a "selection" for a tab control.  So it could be possible, but a bit messy. For example, the header for the tab control is a Canvas with these items nested inside. There's logic handling the positioning absolutely.  The "block" should be able to move visibly all the way across the tab items to the appropriate item.  I will edit my post to reflect this. Upvote for answering my ill-worded question though.

Comment: The thing with Effects is I don't think you can just apply them to TextBlocks.  If each TabItem has other graphical features such as borders and backgrounds, I don't think you can separate them from the TextBlocks while applying a single effect to all your TextBlocks.  You could, in code, create synchronized animations for each TextBlock.  That would be tricky to write though.

Comment: @Moozhe Tricky indeed. I'm currently installing the RC for VS2012 so I will have to wait a bit to make some progress. Why did I do that?!